# How do I destroy an incorrectly-typed instance using Single Table Inheritance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I've just started using Single Table Inheritance. I'm concerned about when a new instance is accidentally made during development, and has a :type that doesn't correspond to an existing subclass. In that case, I am unable to destroy the offending instance, but just get the

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
```

error when I try to do anything with the model at all. The only thing I seem to be able to do is roll back the database and migrate again to remove the object.

Comment: You could go into db console and remote the record directly there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but did you try with:

```
Superclass.destroy(:id);
```

where `superclass` is the class which the other subclasses inherit from and the `:id` is the identifier of the bad instance.

Comment: Yeah, that's when I get this odd ActiveRecord error. The fact that the record exists at all seems to make it impossible to do anything with the model.

Comment: @kateray could you update your question with the related migrations and models please? And also the value of the instance? Thanks